# Likelihood and log-likelihood for Weibull distribution

Tags: self-study, likelihood, weibull-distribution

**Question**

Suppose there are two groups on treatments and an individual follows a Weibull distribution with the following probability density function.

\begin{align}
f(x; \alpha, \lambda) = \alpha \lambda x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\lambda x^{\alpha}}, \quad \text{where } x \geq \alpha \; \text{and } \lambda > 0
\end{align}

It is to be noted $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are known but are not equal to $\alpha = 1$. If participants in the first group, denoted by $x_i$ are modeled by a Weibull distribution $f(x_i; \alpha_1; \lambda_1)$ and participants in the second group are modeled by Weibull distribution $f(y_j; \alpha_2; \lambda_2)$.

What is the likelihood function and log-likelihood function for parameters $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$? Omit terms that do not depend on $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ to faciliate the likelihood equations to find the **MLEs** of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

**Attempt**

For participant group 1, $x_i$,

\begin{align*}
    L_{1}(\lambda_1) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(\alpha_1\lambda_{1}x_i^{\alpha_1 - 1}e^{-\lambda_1 x_i^{\alpha_1}})
\end{align*}

For participant group 2, $y_j$,

\begin{align*}
    L_{2}(\lambda_2) = \prod_{j = 1}^{n}(\alpha_2\lambda_{2}y_j^{\alpha_2 - 1}e^{-\lambda_2 y_j^{\alpha_2}})
\end{align*}

The joint likelihood function would then be.

\begin{align}
L(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= L_{1}(\lambda_1) \cdot  L_{2}(\lambda_2) \\
 &= \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(\alpha_1\lambda_{1}x_i^{\alpha_i - 1}e^{-\lambda_1 x_i^{\alpha_1}}) \cdot \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(\alpha_2\lambda_{2}y_j^{\alpha_2 - 1}e^{-\lambda_1 y_j^{\alpha_2}}) \\
    &= \left(\alpha_1^{n_1}\lambda_{1}^{n_1}x_i^{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(\alpha_1 -1\right)}e^{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(-\lambda_1 x_i^{\alpha_1}\right)}\right) \cdot \left(\alpha_2^{n_2}\lambda_{2}^{n_2}y_j^{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(\alpha_2 -1\right)}e^{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(-\lambda_2 y_j^{\alpha_2}\right)}\right)
\end{align}

The log-likelihood equation would then be with the omission of terms that do not depend on $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are.

\begin{align*}
\ell(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = n_1\ln(\lambda_1) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(-\lambda_1 x_i ^{\alpha_1}\right) + n_2\ln(\lambda_2) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(-\lambda_2 y_j^{\alpha_2}\right)
\end{align*}

**My concerns**

I understand that with this question to find the MLEs for our parameters of interest $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ is that we need to derive the likelihood function with respect to the parameter of interest and set equal to 0. However, I am unsure the approach taken to obtain the likelihood function is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
Upon further commentary provided, it has become clear to me that the we cannot simply take the product of the random variables $x_i$ and $y_j$. The likelihood equation would then be the following when taking the natural log.

\begin{align}
\prod_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^{\alpha_1 - 1} \rightarrow \left(\alpha_1 - 1\right) \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i
\end{align}

Comment: The likelihood is correct. It separates into independent parts for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, which means they can be estimated independently. The derivation of the MLEs follows from standard 1D optimization principles using 1st & 2nd derivatives.